# Why must the first stage be sampled without replacement to get nonzero variance in the second stage?

Tags: self-study, variance, stata, survey, intuition

On page 5 of the [Stata's manual on survey variance estimation](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/svyvarianceestimation.pdf), the following claim is made:

> All but the last stage must be sampled without replacement to get
>   nonzero variance components from each stage of clustered sampling. For
>   example, if $f_h = 0$ (NB: if the fpc of the first stage = 0) in (2),
>   the second stage contributes nothing to the variance estimator.

The equation (2) is:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat V (\hat Y) =& \sum_{h=1}^L(1 -f_h) \frac{n_h}{n_h -1} \sum_{i=1}^{n_h} (y_{hi} - \bar y_h)^2 \\
& + \sum_{h=1}^L f_h \sum_{i=1}^{n_h} (1 - f_{hi}) \frac{m_{hi}}{m_{hi} -1} \sum_{j=1}^{m_{hi}} (y_{hij} - \bar y_{hi})^2
\end{align}
$$

where $h$ identifies the stratum, $(h, i)$ identifies the $i$th PSU in stratum $h$, and $(h,i,j)$ identifies the identifies the $j$th SSU in the $i$th PSU in stratum $h$. $y$ is the outcome, and $n/m$ is the number of PSU within stratum / SSU within PSU.

The claim is indeed true according to equation (2). If $f_h = 0$, the second term, which is the added variance due to the second stage, disappears. However, the text does not justify how equation (2) is derived nor give an intuition.

Could anyone provide mathematical or intuitive support for the claim? A reference for the mathematical proof would be sufficient as well.